# How to set icon inside the main app page in android?

Tags: android, icons

I have an android app and I want to set an icon. I have set the icon using androidmanifest.xml and that shows the icon inside the app list. However, I want the icon to be displayed while the application is running, also. Any help/hints ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to do this. Just make an `ImageView` in one of your view layouts and point it at the icon resource. Style and adjust to your tastes.

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you want your image to be part of the grey title bar that appears by default in activities, I don't think you can do that - but you can easily turn off this title bar and just make your own. To turn off the title bar, just set the theme for the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but theres a catch... I want the icon to appear to the left of the application name (just like a favicon !)...Is there a way to do that ? please let me know. Thanks. :)

Comment: See updated answer - don't think you can insert an image into the existing title, but you can certainly replace it with your own title bar.

Answer (score 2):

i just saw your sentence..........
"I want the icon to appear to the left of the application name" so have used the following in which we can joined it with text view so you can adjust the position of icon....... 
"setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, icon, null, null)".........it is working fine for me....